# Ajaxy - add parameters to request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the jQuery Ajaxy plugin: http://balupton.com/projects/jquery-ajaxy

Is there a way to add POST parameters to each Ajaxy request?

Comment: Could you please specify some more details?

Comment: Always check out the documentation first http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: you guys got me wrong. i meant to type ajaxy.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `$.ajaxSetup()` to set default options - including (GET/POST) data.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: { foo: 'bar' }
});
```

These data will be merged with your data specified in the `$.ajax()` call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/test',
    data: { abc: 123 },
    success: function(resp) { }
});
```

This will send both `foo` and `abc`.

You can also move other options like `type: 'POST'` into your defaults so you don't have to specify it everytime.

Answer (score 3):

According http://visualjquery.com you can also go this way:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: "name=John&location=Boston",
  success: function(msg){
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways is to use `$.param()` -- for a simple example -- using a voting system to vote up/down a comment;

```
<div class="comment_container">
   <div class="vote_container" comment_id="321">
      <a href="javascript:" class="vote vote_up">Up +1</a>
      <a href="javascript:" class="vote vote_down">Down -1</a>
   </div>
   <p>Hello, this a comment!</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.vote').click(function() {
    var voteUpOrDown = $(this).hasClass('vote_up') ? 1 : 0;
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('comment_id');

    $.ajax('/form/rating', {
      type: 'post',
      data: $.param({ vote: voteUpOrDown, id: id }),
      success: function(data) { }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it was 10 years ago but i must write this to here.

The only solution that worked for me is to add the param(s) to the ajax url.
I did it like this:

```
let param = "abc";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: `/test?myParam=${param}`,
    data: { abc: 123 },
    success: function(resp) { }
});
```

If you want to add multiple params you can separate with the end mark like this:

```
let param = "abc";
let param_2 = "cba";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: `/test?myParam=${param}&myParam_2=${param_2}`,
    data: { abc: 123 },
    success: function(resp) { }
});
```

Here is an array version for multiple params:

```
let params = ["asd","foo","bar","etc.."];
let url = "/test?";
for (const [index, param] of params.entries()) {
 url += `myParam_${index}=${param}&`;
}
// Remove last & char from the url
url = url.substring(0, url.length - 1);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: { abc: 123 },
    success: function(resp) { }
});

// Output for the url: "/test?myParam_0=asd&myParam_1=foo&myParam_2=bar&myParam_3=etc.."
```